# New to theano. Trying to add a term to a loss function to penalize negative weights

Tags: theano

To be clear, by weights I mean the entries in the matrices (Ws) of the affine transformation in a node of a neural net.

I start with [`categorical_crossentropy`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#theano.tensor.nnet.nnet.categorical_crossentropy) as my loss function. And I want to add an additional term to penalize negative weights. 
To this end I want to introduce a term of the form

`theano.tensor.sum(theano.tensor.exp(-10 * ws))`

Where "`ws`" are the weights.

If I follow the source code of `categorical_crossentropy`:

```
     if true_dist.ndim == coding_dist.ndim: 
         return -tensor.sum(true_dist *tensor.log(coding_dist), axis=coding_dist.ndim - 1)
     elif true_dist.ndim == coding_dist.ndim - 1:
         return crossentropy_categorical_1hot(coding_dist, true_dist)
     else:
         raise TypeError('rank mismatch between coding and true distributions')
```

Seems like I should update  the third line (from the bottom) to read

```
crossentropy_categorical_1hot(coding_dist, true_dist) + theano.tensor.sum(theano.tensor.exp(- 10 * ws))
```

And change the declaration of the function to be
`my_categorical_crossentropy(coding_dist, true_dist, ws)` Where in calling for `my_categorical_crossentropy` I write

`loss = my_categorical_crossentropy(net_output, true_output, l_layers[1].W)`

with, for a start, `l_layers[1].W` to be the weights coming from the first layer of my neural net.

With those updates, I go on writing:

```
 loss = aggregate(loss, mode = 'mean')  
 updates = sgd(loss, all_params, learning_rate = 0.005) 
 train = theano.function([l_input.input_var, true_output], loss, updates = updates)
[...]
```

This passes the compiler and everything runs smoothly, the training of the network completes. However, for some reason the additional term " `theano.tensor.sum(theano.tensor.exp(- 10 * ws))` is ignored, it seems not to effect the loss value.

I was trying to look into Theano documentation, but so far I could not figure out what might be wrong? The weighs `l_layers[1].W` are shared variables, so I could not pass those as

`train = theano.function([l_input.input_var, true_output, l_layers[1].W], loss, updates = updates)`

Any comments are welcome. Thanks!

### **Solution**

Though, I didn't find why what I did, didn't work, adding the penalty term outside the 'categorical_crossentropy' as suggested in the comments did solve the problem:

```
 loss = aggregate(categorical_crossentropy(net_output, true_output) + theano.tensor.sum(theano.tensor.exp(- 10 * l_layers[1].W))
```

Comment: How does: 

    theano.tensor.sum(theano.tensor.exp(-10 * ws))

Penalize large weights?  It looks like it incentives large weights, actually.  It's also not symmetrical about zero, which in my mind makes it a strange penalty term.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @thc, my mistake I meant negative weights. I have updated the title

Comment: It would help if you had a working example.  exp(-10*ws) is also a really steep exponential, so if your weights are positive, maybe you just aren't seeing the difference in the cost function because it is so small.

Comment: @thc, the resulting weights are negative, I can play with the penalty term but it all appears not to affect the training, so I don't think the specific term is a problem, just the way I am trying to read off the weights. I'll try to provide working example later. What appears strange to me is that I declare 'my_categorical_crossentropy' to have three parameters while in 'train = theano.function([l_input.input_var, true_output], loss, updates = updates)' I only give it two parameters 'l_input.input_var, true_output', but it does not complain... so probably the value for  'ws' is not updated :/.

Comment: If a shared variable is in the updates and the call to grad, it should be updated.  By the way, you should probably take the penalty term outside of the function call.  E.g., loss = aggregate(categorical_crossentropy(net_output, true_output) + theano.tensor.sum(theano.tensor.exp(- 10 * l_layers[1].W))

Comment: @thc, yeah, that solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Great!  According to the documentation crossentropy_categorical_1hot returns a tensor and theano.tensor.sum returns a scalar.  So generally it's best to avoid unnecessary broadcasting and redundancy.  Also, when you said "Seems like I should update the third line (from the bottom) to read", didn't you also need to edit the first return statement?  That may be why.

Comment: @thc you are right, but in my case, I believe, it was always the second if condition that was true, though maybe I have overlooked something...